# CodedUI : The Browser gets closed as finish testing without keeping for testing further steps

Tags: automated-testing, test-design, c#, cross-browser-testing

I'm working on a CodedUI project to check on a Web Solution.

There, when I'm testing for launching the site (as in launching the web URL), I am facing an issue with closing the browser as it finish testing, where it wont allow to use the same browser instance for further testing, Unless if I keep open a instance of a browser (IE) prior manually before running the test.

Can anyone please assist me with this, where I was unable to find a suitable solution. I even went through articles in MSDN where I posted regarding this issue as a comment which I'm facing, since I tried various ways of Code Snippets so far.

- [MSDN](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119174636/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/11/08/using-same-applicationundertest-browserwindow-across-multiple-tests.aspx)
- Stack Overflow: [CodedUI : The Browser gets closed as finish testing without keeping for testing further steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936231/codedui-the-browser-gets-closed-as-finish-testing-without-keeping-for-testing)

My written code is provided below.

```
---
-- common.cs  
[TestMethod]
    public void LoadLocalHost()
    {
      this.UIMap.LoadLocalHost();
    } 
---
-- UIMap.Designer.cs
public void LoadLocalHost()
    { 
      this.UIMsnInternetExplorerWindow.LaunchUrl(new System.Uri("http://localhost:5500/"));
      Console.WriteLine(UIMsnInternetExplorerWindow.CloseOnPlaybackCleanup);
      UIMsnInternetExplorerWindow.CloseOnPlaybackCleanup = false;
    }
```

Highly appreciate an assistance from some one who can.

Answer (score 1):

Preferable you want each test to run in isolation. You don't want any artifacts of a previous test laying around. So closing the browser after each test sounds as a good thing.

A test follows three steps

- Setup: Launch browser, setup database, etc
- Test: Run single testcase
- Teardown: Cleanup

I think you can use TestInitialize and TestCleanup methods, see [the Anatomy of a Unit Test](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182517%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193744/what-would-be-an-alternate-to-setup-and-teardown-in-mstest

Comment: well my current requirement is not to isolate the browser for each step, sir. with that requirement will you be able to assist me further?

Comment: If I start an application with Process.Start then it stays alive during the second test. Maybe that helps. The code: app = Process.Start(_basePath & "Application.exe") https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.110%29.aspx